# C# PowerShell API ServiceProperties usage

Tags: c#, powershell, adfs2.0

I've created a custom attributestore in ADFS 2.0 and one attribute to set is the SsoLifeTime-property from ADFS 2.0.

I'm using the auxillary class ServiceProperties(Link below) but I'm not sure how to really use it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identityserver.powershell.resources.serviceproperties.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

An auxillary class is like a "helper-class(static?)" if I am correct so no instantiation should take place?

Shouldn't I just be able to do like this?

```
int i = ServiceProperties.SsoLifeTime;
```

A workaround would probably be to execute a powershell command using the namespace System.Management.Automation and parse the reponse but I think above solution would be better if it is possible.

Has anyone experience in using the API for the ADFS 2.0 and how to retrieve properties from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the **GetServicePropertiesCommand** as so:

```
var result = new GetServicePropertiesCommand().Invoke();
var enumerator = result.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();

var props = (ServiceProperties) enumerator.Current;
Console.WriteLine(props.SsoLifetime);

// OR using a ForEach loop to enumerate

//foreach (var item in result)
//{
//  var props = (ServiceProperties) item;
//  Console.WriteLine(props.SsoLifetime);
//}
```

To set properties you can use the **SetServicePropertiesCommand**.

Comment: It works for ADFS 2.1 but I haven't used 3 yet...although I can't foreseen a problem with 3.